# Using jQuery .each to loop over XML file

Tags: xml, jquery

I have an XML file that is pretty long.  Below is the code I am using to retrieve the file and then go through the file using jQuery's .each(), outputting the correct information:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('Table').each(function(index){
            var provider = $(this).find('Provider').text();
            var channel = $(this).find('FeedCommonName').text();
            var hd = $(this).find('FeedIsHD').text();
                $('.box ul').append('<li>'+channel+'</li>');
        });
    }
});
});
```

The problem I'm having is the code only gives me up to element 31.  I added the index variable in to see that, and it is giving me an index from 0 to 30.  So is there some limitation that .each() only goes up to an index of 30, and if so, is there another way to go through the XML file?  Thanks.

EDIT: Solved, at least for now.  There were &'s in the XML file, which was holding up the processing.  I guess another reminder to validate your source file first.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no iteration limit on each().  What does $(xml).find('Table').length return?

Comment: Are you sure you have more elements than that in there?  Stick a `console.log($(xml).find('Table').length)` in there and make triple sure.

Comment: It's giving me 32.  So it's not the .each() that's doing it, but there are close to 1000 elements in the XML file.  Why would only 32 be returned?

Comment: Look at the format of the XML file.  Is there a syntax error after the 31st or 32nd entry? Maybe a rogue invalid character?  What is generating this XML file?

Comment: Yeah just figured it out, at least that bit.  There were & in the file, so I had to replace those with &amp;  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using `parseXML` before you find the element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $.parseXML(xml).find('Table').each(function(index){
            var provider = $(this).find('Provider').text();
            var channel = $(this).find('FeedCommonName').text();
            var hd = $(this).find('FeedIsHD').text();
            $('.box ul').append('<li>'+channel+'</li>');
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        $('.box ul').text("Failed to get xml");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I was looking for, after I found the XML document had errors.  It would be impossible for me to fix it everytime