# Count number of xml nodes using JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I know this question has been answered multiple time, but for some reason the code does not work for me. My xml is in this format:

```
<Row>
<data></data>
....
</Row>
```

I am trying to count the number of rows I have in the file. The code I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "xmloutput.xml",
cache: false,
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log('non-IE browser');
    } else {    // IE
        console.log('IE browser')
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    console.log("number of rows:" + $(xml).find('Row').each(function(){}).length);
```

My console display:

```
non-IE browser
number of rows:8
```

The actual number of rows is 520. Firebug also says that my Javascript is error free. Whats going on?

Comment: XML is case sensitive. Are you looking for `Row`, or are you looking for `row`? Also, your feature detect isn't useful on IE11. What IE are you using to test?

Comment: 'Row'. Im sorry. I will edit the xml to reflect that

Comment: The XML you posted is not valid, you are missing a root node. jQuery might still be able to handle that, but in that case, `$(xml)` would be set of Row elements and `.find()` would look for Rows inside Rows.

Comment: I added the root tags just to check, and they make no difference in the result of the code.

Comment: `console.log($(xml).find("Row").each(function () { }).length );` works for me if I wrap with `<Root>` node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery .each to loop over XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070886/using-jquery-each-to-loop-over-xml-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've replicated everything and for me seems that your `XML` file is the problem. Also, If the `dataType` property is specified in the `ajax` call, then there's no need to use `$.parseXML` - *as someone wrote in other answer*. So, is it possible to provide the `XML` file you're using? *(Share it on pastebin or dropbox, just an idea).*

This is what I tried so far and works fine. I'm using an `XML` file with ***500*** `Row` nodes and the output is the expected:

***HTML (index.html):***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="button" id="loadXmlBtn" value="Load XML" />
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***jQuery (js/functions.js):***

```
$(function() {

    var loadXmlBtn = $('#loadXmlBtn');
    var output = $('#output');

    loadXmlBtn.on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'file.xml',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(xml) {
                var node = 'Row', 
                count = $(xml).find(node).length;
                output.html('<b>' + node + '</b> count is: ' + count);
            },
            error: function(r) {
                console.error(r);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

***XML (file.xml):***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <data>Test</data>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

Just to know, I also tried using the following code provided that to be honest, I don't like it but also works fine when getting the count:

```
console.log('number of rows: ' + $(xml).find('Row').each(function(){}).length);
```

Thanks.

Comment: First off, thanks for putting in the work to recreate everything. I can't share the xml file because it has some sensitive data, but I'll be more specific with its format in the OP. Your code also returned 'node count is: 8'.

Comment: Yes, I hope that was the reason but if you can replace all sensitive data by doing some script to replace the values, will be fine and then share - since there's no reason why this code works fine with some dummy `XML` file and not using the one you are working on.

Comment: :D My entire goal at the moment is to be able to loop through the data. I was just printing out the number of rows because I was double-checking my work. If I was able to loop through to erase all the data I would be very happy lol

Answer (score 0):

Okey. If you have an xml like :|

```
<root>
  <Row>
    <data>TEest</data>
    <data2>ddfsdf</data2>
  </Row>
................ 
</root>
```

You can use

```
$(xml).find("Row").length
```

for getting the total number of  nodes.

Comment: Consider using `$.parseXML`.

Comment: Nope. I'm still getting that there are 8 rows

Comment: @FelixKling would $.parseXML replace the $(xml) or would that replace the whole AJAX call

Comment: @yazan: I think there is an example in the documentation. It jus allows jQuery to handle XML correctly and it's used as `$($.parseXML(xml))`. **However** I just noticed that you are already setting the dataType to xml, so that might not be necessary. $.parseXML is only to be used if the argument is a string.

Comment: Whether your xml is wrapped inside a root node ? @yazan

Comment: Yes. I tried with and without the root node and there's no difference

Comment: I think your xml file contains some error. Especially if you copied node contents from browser. There may be some special characters that may be stopping the execution of the xml file. This is a common issue. Try it in that way as well. I am getting the count properly with a test xml file.

Comment: I will double-check the data. Unfortunately this data is being generated from another source which I have no control over.